# How to adapt font size in subscript to provide a coherent look

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I'm trying to define a nice arrow with a dollar above (not too small to make sure it's easy to read, not too big to make sure it does not change the line height too much).

I came up with the below solution, but I've a problem: in the subscripts, my font does not change, which means that my dollar is too big in the subscripts (the dollar goes above the top part of the `{`). Moreover, the spacing before/after my arrow looks a bit small in the subscript version:

[image]

Is there a way to define my symbol is such a way that it looks (proportionally) identical in subscript and in normal text?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\sample{\mathrel{\overset{\vbox to.7ex{\hbox{\fontsize{6}{0}\selectfont\vspace{.5ex} \$}}}{\leftarrow}}}
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello  $b \sample \{0,1\}$ Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello

Here is an equation:
\begin{align}
  b \sample \{0,1\}
\end{align}
Another
\begin{align}
  \Pr_{b \sample \{0,1\}}{1=1}
\end{align}

And the final one $\Pr_{b \sample \{0,1\}}{1=1}$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: your problem is the vbox which is forcing you out of math, you could use \mathchoice, but why not use a standard command such as `\xleftarrow` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for your suggestion, I'll try that. The problem with `\xleftarrow` is that I can't find how to write the text closer to the arrow, `raisebox` with a negative argument does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My favorite playground, namely `\ooalign`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article} % twocolumn just for smaller picture
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\sample}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\sample@\relax}}
\newcommand{\sample@}[2]{%
  \ooalign{%
    \hfil\raisebox{0.7\height}{$\m@th\demotestyle{#1}\mathdollar$}\cr
    $\m@th#1\leftarrow$\cr
  }%
}
\newcommand{\demotestyle}[1]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\scriptstyle\else
  \ifx#1\textstyle\scriptstyle\else
  \scriptscriptstyle\fi\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Here is an equation:
\begin{equation*}
  b \sample \{0,1\}
\end{equation*}

Another
\begin{equation*}
  \Pr_{b \sample \{0,1\}}{1=1}
\end{equation*}

And the final one $\Pr_{b \sample \{0,1\}}{1=1}$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it looks great! And thanks for letting me discover ooalign, I always wanted such function before! I just have two questions, out of curiosity: first, what is the recommended way to shift the dollar sign? For now I use `\hfil\hfil....\hfil` to move it to 2 third of the space, but I guess there is a better way. Also, is there some dimension that scales when changing the mode? I tried `\hspace{1ex}`, but the shift is not the same in both worlds. And finally, if I wanted a more precise control on the font size, what would be the recommended way to proceed?

Comment: @tobiasBora You could use `\hspace{\stretch{2}}` before and `\hspace{\stretch{1}}` after the dollar sign. For “better control” of the font I'm afraid that the only way is scaling.